# selected changed used to find data in another datagridview store previous value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using MS Visual Studio and C#.net 4.0.

So, just completed my other part of my program that checks for duplicates which finally works "many thanks to all that helped".  Showed my boss who liked it but then asked "if he was to select the results of the datagridview that shows the part numbers with duplicate values, is it then possible to highlight the maindatagridview that is equal to the result selected".

Now first of all I understand what he means, but wording this has been rather difficult and as such searching for some examples to get me started has been very difficult.

Now although I don't have any code I can show the code I currently have.

The first thing I did was to identify an event handler on the datagrid that could detect what row is selected, I'm going to use "selectionchanged".

UPDATE:: ok I though I would show you what I meant by re-using my code.
Please note that the code is very similar but is only a starting point, I may incorporate the previous method in with the new one.

```
private void MyErrorGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string getPartSelected;
        getPartSelected = MyErrorGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ParetoGrid.Rows)
        {
            var cellValue = row.Cells["Keycode"].Value;
            if (cellValue != null && cellValue.ToString() == getPartSelected)
            {
                ParetoGrid.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see this works, but there are some problems.  It highlights But doesnt un-highlight, so I think I need to store the previous selected? (not sure this is the best way).

Also need to Add navigation, as highlighting is not good enough for the user. At the moment ive added in selected = true but again when the selection changes i need to use the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this feels like I'm cheating, but here's what I did to solve the problem.

```
private void MyErrorGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string getPartSelected;

        getPartSelected = MyErrorGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();

        foreach(DataGridViewRow allrow in ParetoGrid.Rows)
        {
            ParetoGrid.Rows[allrow.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            ParetoGrid.Rows[allrow.Index].Selected = false;
        }
        //might need a do while
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ParetoGrid.Rows)
        {
            var cellValue = row.Cells["Keycode"].Value;

            if (cellValue != null && cellValue.ToString() == getPartSelected)
            {
                ParetoGrid.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                ParetoGrid.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;


            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see it basically clears all before entering the next change, so it works but without using a previous value.
If anyone has a better solution feel free to answer

The only thing is when there is lots of rows, although it selects and highlights it doesnt scroll the datagridview is there a similar method to do this?